# Yii 2 set up controller to accept json requests

Tags: php, json, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm quite new to Yii 2 but here goes:

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set up a controller that simply reads in any json data posted to it.

I'm slightly confused as to how this works in Yii.

What I've tried so far is set up a controller called ftest to see if I could get it returning some json which seems to work:

```
 public function actionFTest(){
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->add('Content-Type', 'text/json');

    $response = Yii::$app->response;
    $response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $response->data = ['message' => 'Evan .. WHERE ARE YOU?'];

    //$notificationData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);

    //echo var_dump($notificationData);

}
```

Its a bit messy since I've been throwing in code back and forth. I know I should usually return something like $this->render(etc), but I'm not sure what I need to return as a view.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Lot of things are not clear from your post , Like , 1) Where does the json data comes from 2) What do you intend to do with it 3) What should happen after you process the data. ??

Comment: Have a look at the "enabling-json-input" section here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#enabling-json-input -- even if you aren't building an API per se, you should be able to use the examples there to do what you describe.

Comment: Apologies, just to mention:

The data would be posted from another script on another server (a whitelisted IP) to this page/url. The underlying issues behind this I found out to be that data couldn't be posted to this action, which I fixed by enabled CSRF validation:

    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful

```
 use Yii;
    use yii\web\Response;



    public function actionFTest()
    {
          Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    }

Then after that just return a simple array like that:

    return ['param' => $value];
```

Read this 
        http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#$format-detail

Comment: glad to hear from you that it works.. enjoy :) @user3798442

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using behavior and contentNegotiator

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array_merge(
        parent::behaviors(),
        [
            'contentNegotiator' => [
                'class' => 'yii\filters\ContentNegotiator',
                'formats' => [
                    'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
                ]
            ]
        ],
    );
}
```